# CSS width issue on responsive

Tags: css

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o7pfjv3w/. I trying to give to the **grid** class a `margin-left:10px` and `margin-right:10px;` but a scrollbar shows up. How do i get rid of it ?

css code:

```
.main{width: 100%;border:1px solid black;overflow:auto;display:block;}
.grid{width:100%; margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px}
```

html code:

```
<div>
   <div class="main">
       <div class="grid">           <p>ppppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp ppppppppppppppppppppppp ppppppppppppppp</p>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Closed for the reason of the question being already having an answer. Answered with respect to the question's requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has both `margin` and `width: 100%`.

```
.grid{width:100%; margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;}
```

You need to make sure you calculate it. So, instead, give `padding` and make the `box-sizing` to be `border-box`:

```
.grid{width:100%; padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;box-sizing:border-box;}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o7pfjv3w/1/**

Comment: are box-sizing:border-box; working on all browser?

Comment: Yes, (from IE 8+) on modern browsers, you can have a look at [Can I use `box-sizing`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)?

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `overflow:auto;` to `overflow:hidden;`

```
.main{
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden; // not auto
    display:block;
}
```

Here is the updated **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7pfjv3w/3/)**